# picking a random line from stdout

Tags: bash, random

I have a command which spouts a number of lines to stdout:

```
$ listall
foo
bar
baz
```

How do I extract a random entry from this, in a one-liner (preferably without awk) so I can just use it in a pipe:

```
$ listall | pickrandom | sed ... | curl ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
listall | shuf | head -n 1
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed (I didn't know about shuf) - thanks!

Comment: actually "listall | shuf -n 1" seems enough

Answer (score 4):

Some have complained about not having `shuf` available on their installs, so maybe this is more accessible: `listall | sort -R |head -n 1`.
`-R` is "sort randomly".

Comment: I'm afraid `-R` is not available on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with just bash, without other tools other than "listall"

```
$ lists=($(listall)) # put to array
$ num=${#lists[@]} # get number of items
$ rand=$((RANDOM%$num)) # generate random number
$ echo ${lists[$rand]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

- `perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e'print((shuffle<>)[0])'`
- `perl -e'print$listall[$key=int rand(@listall=<>)]'`

Comment: Thank you. While more complex than just using shuf, this might come in handy sometime.

Answer (score 2):

This is memory-safe, unlike using shuf or List::Util shuffle:

`listall | awk 'BEGIN { srand() } int(rand() * NR) == 0 { x = $0 } END { print x }'`

It would only matter if listall could return a huge result.

For more information, see the DADS entry on [reservoir sampling](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML/reservoirSampling.html).

Comment: Good to know, thanks! It's not a concern for this particular case, but I hadn't even thought of this issue before...

Answer (score 0):

Save the following as a script (randomline.sh):

```
#! /bin/sh
set -- junk $(awk -v SEED=$$ 'BEGIN { srand(SEED) } { print rand(), $0 }' | sort -n | head -1)
shift 2
echo "$@"
```

and run it as

```
$ listall | randomline.sh
```